# Run a symfony project on hostgator

Tags: deployment, symfony-1.4

I have been trying to run a symfony project I created recently using symfony 1.4.

But pointing to the url (xyz.in) simply shows up the directory structure of the application

In the CPanel I have edited the `document root` to be upto `app/web/` directory

After doing this all I can see is a blank page and nothing else.

What might be wrong? What are the necessary steps for deploying a symfony project to a shared hosting?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the rights on cache and log directories, Apache needs write rights. Ther are many problems with symfony and shared hosting, but it's not an impossible task.

Comment: Did you have acces to symfony log or apache log ?

Comment: it is working after I changed the third argument to true in the index.php file like this "$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'prod', true);"